# When does option for action end on the big blind?

Tags: rules

I called in small blind, making the hand heads up with me and the big blind. The dealer said "option," looked at the big blind player, and then pulled our chips into the pot as if he were ready to deal. I waited for the flop to come down,and after 3 seconds, the big blind suddenly throws in a huge bet, like 3 big blinds.  I called the floor, because I thought it was an error. The point was moot, because I would have folded anyway; but the point I made is that I have never seen a dealer rake the chips after saying option, and then allow a raise on the big blind. My question is, when is the option for action technically over? I just have never seen this in all my years of playing. The staff gave me some answer like they are just trying to speed up the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fine and pretty standard. The dealer has offered the BB their option to raise and until the BB checks, they should not deal the flop. If the BB raises, then obviously the action is back to you to decide whether to fold, call or raise.

They scooped the chips into the pot in order to speed the game up if the BB does check, as any raise they make will be on top of the 1BB you each already have in the pot and so your 1BB each are always going into the pot whatever happens.

To directly answer your question, the option for action for the BB in this situation is available until they check (at which point the dealer will begin dealing the flop), or in extreme cases until a clock is called on the BB player.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two factors into one complaint which you may not be aware of:

1. Does the big blind have the right to act in that situation?
2. How much time does the big blind have?

The answer to the second one depends on what the rules are at that casino. Some have time limits, most do not.  Would you want to be rushed on a hand when you have $1000's of dollars at stake? It doesn't matter which bet and which order if there is no time limit.

This seems to be where you object to this person's etiquette, that they suddenly acted when you thought (assumed) that he/she wouldn't. That's a mistake if there was no time limit.

Ignore the dealer's actions, they are irrelevant to these questions, and really most dealers are doing what they are told. If the dealer didn't act like there was no further betting then the hand has transitioned to the flop. That would mean the dealer is satisfied the big blind acted. But if the dealer didn't then the house also would side with the dealer and trust his or her judgement.

The answer to the first question is the big blind always has the right to act on an option. How they act, with whatever dramatics or nonsense from your perspective, is not up to anyone else so long as they follow the polite etiquette of a poker table (no abuse, talking during other's hands, etc.).

Since the answer to the first question is affirmative, and provided there was no time limit elapsed, your complaint has no merit.